# Rename columns of dataframe by days in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to rename a dataframe by days in analysis.

```
names(dados) <- c("name", "day_1","Freq_1","Percent_1","day_2","Freq_2","Percent_2",
                  "day_3","Freq_3","Percent_3","day_4","Freq_4","Percent_4",
                  "day_5","Freq_5","Percent_5","day_6","Freq_6","Percent_6",
                  "day_7","Freq_7","Percent_7","day_8","Freq_8","Percent_8",
                  "day_9","Freq_9","Percent_9")
```

I'm doing an analysis that the data I get is in a list of dataframes, where each dataframe represents a day of analysis. I combine the dataframes and I have the columns 'name' unique and 'day_X', 'Freq_X' and 'Percent_X' for each dataframe as a return.

As return I need the columns to have the following names:

"name", "day_1","Freq_1","Percent_1","day_2","Freq_2","Percent_2","day_3","Freq_3","Percent_3"

How do I go about analyzing 50 days?

reproducible example:

```
day1 <- data.frame(name = c("jose", "mary", "julia"), freq = c(1,5,3), percent = c(40,30,20))
day2 <- data.frame(name = c("abner", "jose", "mary"), freq = c(3,5,4), percent = c(20,30,20))
day3 <- data.frame(name = c("abner", "jose", "mike"), freq = c(6,2,3), percent = c(40,30,70))
day4 <- data.frame(name = c("andre", "joseph", "ana"), freq = c(1,5,8), percent = c(40,30,20))
day5 <- data.frame(name = c("abner", "poli", "joseph"), freq = c(4,3,3), percent = c(10,30,10))

dates <- list(day1,day2,day4,day5)

data <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "name", all = TRUE), dates)
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible example of your list with data.frames.

Comment: @MKR I added in the question :D

Comment: What does the `dayN` variables supposed to represent? Is it just a static day variable with a constant across all rows?

Comment: What about changing the names after merging like this? `names(data)[-1] = paste(rep(c("freq", "percent"), length(dates)), rep(1:length(dates), each = 2), sep = "_")

`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get what you want using the `tidyverse` suite of packages. We start by putting the data in the "long" format - but add a column with the date:

```
long_form <- dates %>%
  imap_dfr(function(x, y) dplyr::mutate(x, day_num = y))
```

Now, to get the wide format you are after, we need to reformat things a bit, as done in the following code.  I'm not sure what is supposed to go in the `day_#` variables, as @useR mentioned in the comments, so it's missing.  If you have a variable called `day`, the code should automatically do the right thing as written.

```
wide_form <- long_form  %>%
  gather(key, value, -name,-day_num) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    key = paste(key, day_num, sep = "_")
  ) %>%
  select(-day_num) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use `dplyr::bind_rows` to merge all data frames form the list to a data frame. Please provide `name` to list so that `day1`, `day2` etc can set beforehand. Finally, `gather` and `spread` is used to transform the data.

```
names(dates) <- paste("day", seq_along(dates), sep = "")

library(tidyverse)

bind_rows(dates,.id = "Name") %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  gather(Key, value, -Name,-rn) %>%
  unite("Key", c("Key", "Name")) %>%
  spread(Key, value) %>%
  select(-rn)
```

**Result:**

```
# # A tibble: 3 x 12
#  freq_day1 freq_day2 freq_day3 freq_day4 name_day1 name_day2 name_day3 name_day4 percent_day1 percent_day2 percent~ percent~
#   * <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>        <chr>        <chr>    <chr>   
# 1 1         3         1         4         jose      abner     andre     abner     40           20           40       10      
# 2 5         5         5         3         mary      jose      joseph    poli      30           30           30       30      
# 3 3         4         8         3         julia     mary      ana       joseph    20           20           20       10     
#
```

**Data:**

Data is slightly modified from OP. I have included `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument as part of `data.frame` to avoid a `mutate_at` call to convert `factor` to `character`.

```
day1 <- data.frame(name = c("jose", "mary", "julia"), freq = c(1,5,3), percent = c(40,30,20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
day2 <- data.frame(name = c("abner", "jose", "mary"), freq = c(3,5,4), percent = c(20,30,20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
day3 <- data.frame(name = c("abner", "jose", "mike"), freq = c(6,2,3), percent = c(40,30,70), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
day4 <- data.frame(name = c("andre", "joseph", "ana"), freq = c(1,5,8), percent = c(40,30,20), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
day5 <- data.frame(name = c("abner", "poli", "joseph"), freq = c(4,3,3), percent = c(10,30,10), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dates <- list(day1,day2,day4,day5)
```